# Dúvida plataforma Python

Tags: python

Estou aperfeiçoando meus conhecimentos para o mercado de trabalho e decidi estudar a linguagem Python e queria saber referente ao mercado e a "vantagem" da linguagem para qual lado eu focaria, se eu estudo Python mais focado para WEB ou se estudo mais voltado para sistemas desktops?
Irei dar uma olhada nas versões também mas eu devo ignorar as versões antecessoras e focar mais nas versões 3.0 ?

Comment: Quanto a versão foque na mais recente!